# Воспользоваться windows location href или пересобрать адрес ссылки?

Tags: php

Нужно в профиле пользователя указывать ссылки на страницы, где он оставлял комментарии, поэтому вопрос: как лучше - передать ссылку со страницы с которой был отправлен комментарий с помощью windows location href или собрать её заново, сделав несколько запросов в БД?

Ссылка имеет вид: site.com/a/angels/1-all-about-angels.html

Второй способ затратный и приходится делать 3 запроса:

1ый, в таблицу с новостью, где указана категория в которой размещена новость, её id и адрес на латинице /1-all-about-angels

2ой, в таблицу категорий, где нужно: a) взять адрес на латинице b) узнать ID категорию родителя. Получаем /angels

3ий, взять адрес родителя на латинице /a

Стоит ли так изворачиваться и нагружать сервер или все же пренебречь корректностью ссылок? Я не думаю, что нормальные пользователи специально будут менять windows location href в отладчике.

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос

Comment: то, что вы описали - делается одним запросом.

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: Вообщем, я решил сделать так: ссылку на страницу не добавлять в таблицу, при заходе в раздел профиля пользователя один раз получу все поля категорий, и потом выберу из таблицы комментариев все поля с нужным пользователем, объединяя с таблицей новостей, где и находятся нужные записи, дальше сформирую все ссылки функцией.